# Minimum estimation

Tags: calculus, analysis, gelfand-shilov-spaces

Hi could anyone explain me how one come sup with the term circled with red? The proof tries to show that for integer numbers the mimimum is somewhere else (a bit higher) than it would be if f would be continous ($k_{0}$ is where the minimum is btw). Thanks!

[image: Proof]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality probably comes from the Taylor expansion of $\ln(f)$ about $k_0$, since you're told the second derivative.

Since $k_1$ is the integer closest to the right of $k_0$ the difference between them is less than $1$ so the square of the difference is less than $1$. Then omitting that factor strengthens the inequality.

Comment: ok that would explain the estimation there. but how does one come up with the term in the left red circle?

Comment: @craft See my edit.

Comment: Damn, missed that taylor series. how embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: what I am not sure about is the point of having $k_{2}$ though. It actually should be just $k_{0}$

Comment: No. The $k_2$ is an intermediate point that makes the correction term an equality. Its existence is guaranteed by some theorem on the remainder term in the expansion. Maybe Lagrange.

Comment: Do you know exactly the theorem? Normally one has the remainder as additional term rather than a correction factor.

Comment: For the remainder, try the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder . As to the missing first order term, I've no idea. Maybe the context tells you something about the first derivative.

Comment: well. $k_{0}$ is the mimum so the derivative at this point is 0.